# What contemporary criticism was given to Belloc's claim that the Protestant Reformation was the work of a few oligarchs?

Tags: protestantism, church-history, reformation

I've just returned from the 33rd Conference of the American Chesterton Society with exciting news,  apparently Protestantism is a sham inflicted upon us by the corporate elite!

Hehehe, well who knows... But I've been on this site as long as anyone and I found it very surprising to hear Hilare Belloc's thesis on the over-arching cause of the reformation.  I knew from reading the Servile State that after the Reformation it was apparent that the lords looted the monasteries.

> "What! this large national movement to be
>   interpreted as the work of such minorities? A few thousand squires and
>   merchants backing a few more thousand enthusiasts, changed utterly the mass
>   of England?" Yes; to interpret it otherwise is to read history backwards.
>   It is to think that England then was what England later became. There
>   is no more fatal fault in the reading of history, nor any illusion to
>   which the human mind is more prone. To read the remote past in the light
>   of the recent past; to think the process of the one towards the other
>   "inevitable;" to regard the whole matter as a slow inexorable process,
>   independent of the human will, still suits the materialist pantheism of our
>   time. There is an inherent tendency in all men to this fallacy of reading
>   themselves into the past, and of thinking their own mood a consummation
>   at once excellent and necessary: and most men who write of these things
>   imagine a vaguely Protestant Tudor England growing consciously Protestant
>   in the England of the Stuarts.
>
> [Hilaire Belloc - Europe and the Faith](http://www.gutenberg.org/dirs/etext05/rpnft10.txt)

But, does anyone have any evidence against the notion that it was what would become the aristocracy who started the reformation in Britain?  Did people take Belloc seriously.  I've read recently that he's been found correct time and time again, but always seen as a heavy handed Catholic reactionary in his day (which makes him quite a hero to me) who no one took seriously because he wrote in a vulgar manner and not only for scholars.

Comment: I feel the question is unclear. Are you asking (partly) whether reformers like Luther, Calvin, Zwingli, etc. got their marching orders from greedy nobles? I guess what I'm saying is that the words "started the reformation" are a bit loosey-goosey.

Comment: yeah, by started I mean was the impetus for making it what it wound up being and not what St. Francis of Assisi, St. Theresa of Avila or St. Catherine of Sienna did when they thought the Church needed reform.

Comment: So are you asking whether or at what point the political hierarchy started exerting a major influence in the course of the Reformation? Or are you asking something else?

Comment: I'm pretty sure 99.99% of such shenanigans would have been just post hoc opportunism, it would seem inherently difficult to prove in a proper answer though - the Princes are hardly going to own up to dubious motives like that and anybody else will just be speculating. I'm guessing the best case that may support the thesis would be England - an examination of the degree to which Henry VIII-Edward VI-Mary-Elizabeth's power plays influenced the Reformation in England vs the influence the Reformation had on them. I really think you'd need a book just for the English case, let alone other countries

Comment: @MattGutting I'm asking whether Belloc is right or if he's ever had anyone critique his argument.  Most of what I've heard is silence.

Comment: @bruisedreed a bibliography would be sufficient. The only annoying thing about reading Belloc and Chesterton is that I always agree with everything they say!

Comment: @PeterTurner so does Luther himself count as 'bottom' or is he merely 'middle'?

Comment: @bruisedreed bottom.  In my opinion what he did would be like you or me nailing some treatise on natural law on the Supreme Court building.  The rest of the bottom may have swelled around him to bring his theories of theology to the forefront or the top may have used him as a willing dupe to grab up vast tracts of land (that's the question)

Comment: @PeterTurner To answer whether Belloc is right, it would be most helpful to get a clear statement of his premise. I don't know whether _The Servile State_ or any of his other writings contains a convenient, brief summary in his own words - which I think would be the most helpful starting point.

Comment: @PeterTurner forgive me for an extended comment exchange, but I'm trying to work out if your question can be anything more than just opinion based. Not being familiar with Belloc's work, may I ask to what level does he demonstrate an expert knowledge of the life of Luther in order to advance his thesis?

Comment: @PeterTurner by all accounts I've heard/read, the case in Scotland seems clear enough - emphatically bottom up cf. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_knox - does Belloc talk about the Scottish experience at all?

Comment: @bruisedreed I'll try to find one thing,  he wrote like 153 books and a 5 volume history of Europe so it might be tough.  I never connected the dots when reading the Servile State as that was mostly about England and even in The Great Heresies I don't remember any economic reason for the reformation being brought up.  This was verbally communicated through lectures at the Chesterton Society meeting I eluded to, so I'll have to dig up references in books I don't own.

Comment: `Was the Protestant Reformation a bottom-up or top-down reformation` -- I'm pretty sure the answer to this question is simply: **Yes**.  It's far too complex a scenario to pigeon-hole into either view. Both views are applicable to some aspects, and other aspects of the reformation wouldn't fit into either view.

Comment: @MattGutting just finished reading Europe and the Faith and this was probably the most succinct quote from the book.   The looking of the monestaries was hit on in the Servile State, but here's where he really explains what happened.

Comment: The "magisterial reformation" (Luther, Calvin, Zwingli) was basically the work of a few oligarchs, but the "radical reformation" (Anabaptists, Socinians, etc.) was clearly the work of a wider range of society.

Comment: @davidbrainerd Why do you say that the Swiss reformations was the work of a few oligarchs? The Swiss cantons were largely independent, and governed by councils, not individuals. In that kind of environment any changes need broad support.

Comment: Belloc's theory could only be plausible if all of Luther's & others' arguments for the illegitimacy of the Catholic church were bizarre fabrications instead of substantially sound Biblical interpretation. (In other words, if it were all a plot cooked up by power-hungry oligarchs, how did they engineer the Bible to support the claims that the Catholic church was _way_ off the mark?) If you reject the arguments against the Catholic church's illegitimacy, then the place to start is with with those arguments, not with a question that requires one to simple _assume_ a position on those arguments.

Answer (score 6):

What a fascinating question -

```
Was the Protestant Reformation a bottom-up or top-down reformation?
```

It would seem the only reasonable answer is - **Yes!** (i.e. both)

The progress of the Reformation in Scotland showed all the hallmarks of the former - cf. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_knox :

> John Knox (c. 1514 – 24 November 1572) was a Scottish clergyman, writer and a leader of the Protestant Reformation...

While it's genesis in England showed distinct signs of the latter - cf. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_viii#Reformation :

> Henry is generally credited with initiating the English Reformation – the process of transforming England from a Catholic country to a Protestant one...

Of course, the crux of the matter is - what was the situation in Continental Europe and in particular, what were the circumstances surrounding [Martin Luther](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_luther) and the very beginning of the Reformation?  Was Protestantism really birthed out of the objections a Theology professor had to the '[Indulgance Industry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indulgences#Late_medieval_abuses)', or were there dark forces at work behind the scenes - worldly potentates plotting to appropriate ecclesiastical booty for their own aggrandizement - pulling Luther's strings?  Well according to most accounts (at least the ones that don't have a specific axe to grind), the evidence points very much to the former (cf The Economist's article *[How Luther went viral](http://www.economist.com/node/21541719)*).  While the nascent Reformation did catch the eye of at least [some Princes relatively early on](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederick_III,_Elector_of_Saxony), it wasn't until some years later that this translated into official breaks with recognized Church (and in the case of the member states of the Holy Roman Empire, temporal) authority which admittedly bore some prospect of enrichment at the expense of the church, but also the high likelihood of war with states loyal to Rome - it was no light undertaking, and it least in the case of the German states, was far more likely to be the result of [conviction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augsburg_confession) than opportunism. (cf. [source 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmalkaldic_League),[source 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmalkaldic_War) & [source 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty_Years%27_War))

```
Is there more evidence that there was actually something in Reformed 
Christianity that appealed to the peasant?
```

Absolutely: The Reformation all started with preaching against (purchaseable) indulgances - which amounted to enabling the rich to buy their way out of purgatory. Of course to the extant that a peasant was aware of the practice, he was aware of an injustice - perceiving the church favoring the rich;  In contrast the doctrine of salvation by grace alone through faith alone - the free gift of God through Christ - would have been the very breath of heaven on his soul.  Although Luther himself criticized what he saw as the excesses of the Peasant's rights movement that lead to the [German Peasant's war](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_Peasants%27_War), and there were many factors that precipitated that conflict, adoption of Protestant doctrines (especially those that pertain to choosing revealed truth ahead of obedience to earthly authority) were a definite part of the mix.

***Summary:*** Although there was a measure of top-down influence on the development of the Reformation (especially in England), the dominant characteristic was actually bottom-up and Belloc's thesis is not well supported by a comprehensive overview of the genesis of Protestantism.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I hardly believe his thesis isn't extremely well supported. But since I couldn't clearly state it or defend it, you've at least pointed me to a good place to start looking to poke holes in it!

Comment: Belloc may have been focused on the English Reformation, particularly with the reference to _looting the monasteries_, which was very much an English phenomenon.

Comment: @MattGutting There was looting in Scotland as well, but it was actually driven by the mob - mainly in response to Knox's preaching.

Comment: Agreed. England had not so much looting as wholesale reassignment of property.

Comment: @matt that's a euphemism if ever I've heard one! Not that I'm bitter, I just want my middle ages back.

Comment: @PeterTurner "I just want my middle ages back." If you had a really clear picture of what they were like, I don't think you would - The hegemony of Church over society was neither healthy for the Church nor for the people. If the church 'becomes the world' then essentially the lampstand has been removed (cf. Revelation 2:5). Excommunication and death for merely possessing a bible in english and you want to go back to that?!